# Why doesn't datediff for week work?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date

This was a bug that took awhile to find. I post it here to save someone else this mistake.

(It's extremely simple once it is found, but it is any easy -- and costly -- mistake to make.)

Why does `select datediff(w, getdate()-7, getdate())` give 7 instead of 1?

Comment: *Asked 1 min ago* ... -> *Answered 19 secs ago*... You thought of the answer while writting the question ?

Comment: I already had the answer when I posted...after a lot of searching and some upset customers. I intended to help anyone else stuck as I was. I understand that is not uncommon on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `w` is interpreted as days. It is never mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx), but inexplicably it seems to mean days. (I don't know why this doesn't give an error, as `datediff(foo, getdate()-7, getdate())` does...)

The correct unit for week is `ww` or `wk`.

Edit: @Lamak says that `w` is weekday instead of day. There is nothing (I can find) documented about `w`, but this may be correct.

Comment: Stop using any type of shorthand. Guess what `DATEPART(Y, GETDATE());` yields?

Comment: you can't just use whatever on that parameter, `foo` being one of them. But `w` is `weekday`, so it is accepted and the result is correct. But, as Aaron said, you should always use `WEEK` or `WEEKDAY` or the complete name instead

Comment: Day of year, as documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx. FYI, I do not see anything *except* shorthand in that documentation.

Comment: @Paul, you 100% missed my point. Would you have *guessed* that if you didn't have the documentation sitting in front of you? Would your readers, boss, co-workers also make such an astute guess? If you mean WEEK, say WEEK. There is no harm in typing three extra characters and being absolutely crystal clear and unambiguous.

Comment: @PaulDraper What do you mean you don't see anything but shorthands?, the `Abbreviations` are the shorthands and the `datepart` are, well, the complete name you should use

Comment: Oh...I see, @Lamak, you are correct. And I do agree...long names are better. Thank you. You and Aaron certainly are better than whoever chose to (do extra work to!) put those abbreviations in TSQL.

Comment: @Paul If you looked at the Examples at the bottom of the documentation page (which you should always do) you would have seen the full datepart names being used in the function calls.